# vmware player on windows 7 ,after windows upgrade from Vista, not showing Ethernet port

Tags: vmware-player, windows-7

I have just updated laptop to Windows 7 and VMWare Player is not connecting to the NIC so I can't use my Ubuntu VM to connect to somthing outside of itself

Below is the VMWare.log for when its going wrong. I have Google'd for it and can't find the answer so hoping you lovely people can help me :)

```
Dec 21 19:17:08.697: vmx| TOOLS received request in VMX to set option 'synctime' -> '0'
Dec 21 19:17:08.730: vmx| VMXVmdb_LoadRawConfig: Loading raw config
Dec 21 19:19:00.088: mks| Setting thread 40 stack size to 1048576.
Dec 21 20:23:02.392: mks| Setting thread 40 stack size to 1048576.
Dec 21 20:23:05.127: vmx| VNET: MACVNetPort_Connect: Ethernet1: can't get driver version (6)
Dec 21 20:23:05.127: vmx| Msg_Post: Error
Dec 21 20:23:05.127: vmx| [msg.vnet.connectvnet] Could not connect Ethernet1 to virtual network "VMnet8". More information can be found in the vmware.log file.
Dec 21 20:23:05.127: vmx| [msg.device.badconnect] Failed to connect virtual device Ethernet1.
Dec 21 20:23:05.127: vmx| ----------------------------------------
Dec 21 20:23:09.371: vmx| TOOLS received request in VMX to set option 'synctime' -> '0'
Dec 21 20:23:09.403: vmx| VMXVmdb_LoadRawConfig: Loading raw config
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching and searching a simple uninstall and reinstall got it working again.